# DocuSign Custom Button for Document Review

Tags: docusignapi

We currently are using DocuSign for Salesforce and use a custom button on an object which creates a envelope (using a template) with three signers. One signer is the host and the other two are sign in person. Basically at the moment the other two signers who are sign in person have to be present in the room at the same time to sign when the document have been completed by the host, we can resume the signing process by loading the last auto email from DocuSign and clicking "review document" but we are looking to see if we could create a custom button in the DocuSign status object to resume a document so that the host could complete the document in office and then resume the document so it goes to the next signer when they visit the signers. This does work when loading the last email and clicking review document but we are looking to see how we could create a custom button to "review the document" as such so it resumes it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Many Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

To resume the DocuSign signing process outside of a DocuSign email you need to use a Request Recipient Token API call which returns a unique signing session URL for that recipient. You can then render that URL within Salesforce.

I don't think it is possible to do this using the custom button approach. Reason being, the Request Recipient Token API call requires a 'Client User ID' for the recipient in question. The 'Client User ID' is set during envelope creation. With the custom button approach you don't have the opportunity to set the 'Client User ID'.

You could achieve the review and sign later functionality using APEX to call the DocuSign SOAP or REST API for envelope creation and then to retrieve recipient tokens as needed.

I've done something similar [here](https://github.com/markjkelly/Salesforce/blob/master/EmbeddedSigningMultiple/src/classes/DocuSignNowController.cls) using the SOAP API. In that case I didn't need to resume later so I just set the 'Client User ID' sequentially. In your case you may need to store it within the SF object from which you are invoking DocuSign.

[Here](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/implementing-an-nda-signing-ipad-application-using-salesforcecom-and-the-docusign-api) is a tutorial which may also help you to become familiar with using DocuSign via APEX.